# How to change the Range for the Location of Workbook and Sheet in macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, macros

I have Found a macro on this site:
[How can I compare two columns in Excel to highlight words that don't match?](https://superuser.com/questions/664926/how-can-i-compare-two-columns-in-excel-to-highlight-words-that-dont-match/664979#664979?newreg=7b0bd96dfb144bbe85d14cd84219c3f0)

My question is how can i change the link or the range of the column to different Workbook/worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

While defining your range, you can use the following format to add the names of worksheet and -book explicitly:

```
[Book1]Sheet1!A1:A9
```

Alternatively you can set your range via VBA code.

Comment: How can i convert it to VBA code

Answer (score 0):

In the answer you have this -

> Just be sure to change the addresses in the lines below to match your
> worksheet.
>
> `Set rng2HL = Range("A1:A9")`
>
> `Set rngCheck = Range("B1:B9")`

That is where the ranges are defined.

Comment: Yes but how can i link to another workbook and worksheet?

Comment: `set rng2HL = '[Book1]Sheet1!A1:A9` [documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-HP010102338.aspx)