# How can i compare 2 columns row by row in excel and then extract unique information?

Tags: vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2016

**My Question(s):**

1) Being able to compare **Column A** word in **Column B** and highlight the difference but doing this comparison row by row between the 2 columns.

Iam working with a large data set of 48k+ rows and iam trying to compare if column b contains any words from column A. Column A may only make part of the text string in column B for example:
Column A = Achmina
Column B = Football club Achmina

The above would be a match of column B against column A but not from row to row the position of the text in column A will differ in Column B. I have used the code below for the above from this question: [How can I compare two columns in Excel to highlight words that don't match?](https://superuser.com/questions/664926/how-can-i-compare-two-columns-in-excel-to-highlight-words-that-dont-match)

The VBA code is as follows:

```
Sub highlightWords()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim rng2HL As Range, rngCheck As Range, dictWords As Object
Dim a() As Variant, b() As Variant, wordlist As Variant, wordStart As Long
Set r = Selection
'Change the addresses below to match your data.
Set rng2HL = Range("A1:A9")
Set rngCheck = Range("B1:B9")
a = rng2HL.Value
b = rngCheck.Value
Set dictWords = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
'Load unique words from second column into a dictionary for easy checking
For i = LBound(b, 1) To UBound(b, 1)
    wordlist = Split(b(i, 1), " ")
    For j = LBound(wordlist) To UBound(wordlist)
        If Not dictWords.Exists(wordlist(j)) Then
            dictWords.Add wordlist(j), wordlist(j)
        End If
    Next j
Next i
'Reset range to highlight to all black font.
rng2HL.Font.ColorIndex = 1
'Check words one by one against dictionary.
For i = LBound(a, 1) To UBound(a, 1)
    wordlist = Split(a(i, 1), " ")
    For j = LBound(wordlist) To UBound(wordlist)
        If Not dictWords.Exists(wordlist(j)) Then
            wordStart = InStr(a(i, 1), wordlist(j))
            'Change font color of word to red.
            rng2HL.Cells(i).Characters(wordStart, Len(wordlist(j))).Font.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next j
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The above code give mes part of the picture but on further review is not 100% accurate for my purpose as it searches all of column B for words in column A wheras i require it row by row as the relation of the data in each of the rows between column A and B is 1 to 1.

I have tried

> VLOOKUP, EXACT MATCH, INDEX MATCH

but had no luck whatsoever and a iam not a superuser of VBA or Macros thus any idiot proof guidance would be great please!

**My second Question is as follows:**

2) Once i know the difference between column **A** and **B** and have been able to flag the differences i then want to extract the truly unique record, as the data is currently structured with a primary key ID but repeated for different sources:

> Primary Key ID - 01200

**Data Source A:**

> Client Name - James Smith

**Data Source B:**

> Client Name - James Smi

**Data Source C:**

> Client Name - James Smith Steve

Thus for primary **key ID - 01200** i need to extract the unique record based on client name - James Smith but need to cross validate this with the other data sources.

I am not sure how to do the above whether to use VBA or Macros but for either i would not be quite sure where to start - so would much appreciate your help here also!